# Java - Trying to make a timer

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a timer that goes from 15 minutes to 0 but my code doesn't work. Sorry if this is easy, I recently started learning.

```
package timer;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Timer {
    int secondsLeft = 900;
    int minutesLeft = secondsLeft/60;
    int seconds2 = secondsLeft - minutesLeft * 60;

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            secondsLeft--;
            System.out.println("Time left : " + minutesLeft + ":" + seconds2 );
        }
    };

    public void start() {
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000, 1000);        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information about what you tried so far and what's exactly the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is mostly written correctly, but you are not printing any changes.  When the seconds count down, you need to convert existing `total seconds` to `minutes` and `seconds`.

You can do it several ways.

**Method 1:** Like you are doing it now, by
maintaining a total number of seconds.  It requires two operators.

- The division operator `/`
- The remainder operator `%`

To get the minutes remaining, simply divide total seconds by `60`.  `(totalSeconds / 60)`
To get the seconds remaining in the current minute take the remainder `(totalSeconds % 60)`

**Method 2:** By maintaining separate values for `minutes` and `seconds`, where `seconds` is the number of `seconds` within the current minute.

- define a `int minutes` field initialized to `15`
- define a `int seconds` field initialized to `0`

When the timer task runs, you need to update those fields correctly.  When the seconds reach `0`
decrement the minutes and set the seconds to `59`.  Otherwise, just decrement the seconds.
When they both reach `0`, you're done.  So this requires some `if clauses` on your part.

**Additional Recommendations**

To retain the leading zeroes of minutes and seconds, you can use the following formatted print statement.

```
 System.out.printf("Time left : %02d:%02d%n",minutesLeft, secondsLeft);
```

The `%02d` is the field width and the `0` means keep leading zeroes to fill out that field. To learn more about formatted printing, check out the [Formatter class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) in the Java API.

And finally, please call you class something other than `Timer`.  You are using a `Timer` class by that name already and even though it is in the same package it can be confusing.